# Why does Counter-Strike Source have low frame rate?

Tags: counter-strike-source

I'm using nVidia GTS 450, a card in midrange of GPUs. It allows me to play Battlefield 2 at frame rate of almost 100 frames per second (with all graphic settings set to max).

However, I can play Counter-Strike Source at only 20 frames per second (map de_inferno for example).

Is Counter-Strike Source too bad at graphic optimisation?

Comment: The source engine has always been one of the most forgiving for me in terms of performance on bad hardware. Are your drivers up to date?

Comment: Check your render in Video options, make sure you're using "OpenGL" and not "Software."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People complain a lot about this,with new high end graphic cards they would still get low framerates(not nearly low as 20 but still).

Open ingame console and write `fps_max 100` it can go even higher but no point...This is in case your max FPS is limited.

Changing your .cfg file is another option, [here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/95162-25-tomshardware) you can find more details.

Other than that you could change your driver options or ingame options.

Comment: I very much doubt fps_max is the problem.

Comment: @kotekzot Would be good to hear from the OP if this actually solved his problem. Sometimes answers are accepted but disputed on good grounds.